# Android Studio Ugly Font(Anti aliasing)

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

I am using Android Studio on Deepin linux 15.8, but it is difficult to work with it because of the ugly font rendering. Here are some screen-shots.

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this happen to you with other screen resolutions?
For me 4K resolution sometimes make issues with fonts.

Comment: I have a only one resolution screen. 1920x1080. There was no such problem. Then started

Comment: Post the solution as an answer instead of editing it into the question